# How to make a Visual Form editing after pasting the form code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

I'm stuck with a problem. Here is what I want to do:

I want to copy / paste a HTML form code in a textarea.
And then be able to "visually" edit this form, arrange the elements etc... But from the HTML code that I pasted.

For example, someone get a newsletter registration HTML form from an autorespondeur, paste the code in my system and can arrange and add visual effets, colors, etc..

I didn't find a satisfying solution for now.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: you need javascript wysiwyg editor

Comment: Yes, but I've been searching for one for hours, and I didn't find anything satisfying

Answer (score 0):

use tinyMce, it easy to integrate in any form, https://www.tiny.cloud/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to integrate a texteditor in a form ; I want to be able to edit the form itself : drag and drop inputs to change the position, change the texts placeholder, the submit button color, the background color etc;..